# Is there a way to build Rust for the x32 ABI?

Tags: rust

LLVM supports x32. Is there a way to cross compile Rust for this ABI - without support for the Linux kernel and other syscalls. Just the code.

Comment: Would that be the [`x86_64_unknown_linux_gnux32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_target/spec/x86_64_unknown_linux_gnux32/index.html) target?

Comment: *to cross compile Rust* — so you want `rustc` to use the x32 ABI? Or do you want to compile your **own** code for x32?